# Reference month in table from two cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logic

It looks like a simple and trivial task that I should know... but I'm not good as expected with excel :(

Task: Given the cells `E4 (language's code)` and `E9 (month's number)`.

How to set the correct value to `E10 (month's name)`?

[image]

Details: As `E4` refers to `B5 - Português` it should look into `J-column` where the month's number is equal to `E9` and take its name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this a few ways...

Quick way would be too use a Vlookup function in cell E10 that would look like below :

=VLOOKUP($E$9,$H$4:$K$15,$E$4 + 1)

For info on how the Vlookup works refer to : 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Cheers,
Bob

Answer (score 1):

This just needs a simple INDEX/MATCH combinination.

INDEX takes a given range of data, and provides the result based on the row/column # which you specify. MATCH takes a given range of data, and looks for a search term, providing you with the row/column number. You could convert the month into a name in a variety of ways, but I will use the auto-conversion available using the TEXT function. TEXT takes a number and gives you the result as text, formatted in a specific way. It can convert a date into a specific type of data based on this format.

This would work like so with your example:

```
=INDEX($I$4:$K$15,MATCH(TEXT( E7,"MMMM"),$H$4:$H$15,0),E4)
```

INDEX here takes the 2-D data block with the 3 translations for each month. It then attempts to MATCH the month found in E7, with column H. It pulls the matching row number, and then it takes the column number equal to the 'selected language' cell.